# multicolor line on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors

Is it possible to have something similar to `edgecolor` and `facecolor` for plt.plot()? I need to plot a curve with a different colored boundary around it for e.g. a segment of the line would look like ||| with the outer lines in a different color and the inner line in a different color. Can this be done using a single plot command rather than plotting three plots?

Comment: No it can't. A line is a line, which has no edge. You may define a polygon instead. Or you may draw 3 parallel lines.Depending on the use case this can range from just repeating the call to `plot` 3 times to something like shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42190453/4124317).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest a line _can_ have an edge if you define its `path_effects` using a `Stroke`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using the [`matplotlib.patheffects`](https://matplotlib.org/api/patheffects_api.html) module. You can set the `path_effect` of a line by using the [`path_effects` kwarg](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_path_effects.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_path_effects).

Specifically in this case, we can use the [`Stroke`](https://matplotlib.org/api/patheffects_api.html#matplotlib.patheffects.Stroke) class for the outline, and the [`Normal` class](https://matplotlib.org/api/patheffects_api.html#matplotlib.patheffects.Normal) for the inner part of the line (this just uses the linewidth and color specified by `plt.plot`). See the example below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.plot(np.random.rand(5), linewidth=4, color='r', path_effects=[
    path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=8, foreground='black'),
    path_effects.Normal()
    ])

plt.show()
```

[image]