# 'range' object does not support item assignment in python3

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors

How to solve this error:

File "rainbow.py", line 53, in plot_rainbow

xr[0],yr[0] = offset_curve(ax, x,y, lw/2.)

TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment

in the following code, please? I tried to replace range with xrange, but it does not help.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dpi = 100

def offset(x,y, o):
    """ Offset coordinates given by array x,y by o """
    X = np.c_[x,y].T
    m = np.array([[0,-1],[1,0]])
    R = np.zeros_like(X)
    S = X[:,2:]-X[:,:-2]
    R[:,1:-1] = np.dot(m, S)
    R[:,0] = np.dot(m, X[:,1]-X[:,0])
    R[:,-1] = np.dot(m, X[:,-1]-X[:,-2])
    On = R/np.sqrt(R[0,:]**2+R[1,:]**2)*o
    Out = On+X
    return Out[0,:], Out[1,:]


def offset_curve(ax, x,y, o):
    """ Offset array x,y in data coordinates
        by o in points """
    trans = ax.transData.transform
    inv = ax.transData.inverted().transform
    X = np.c_[x,y]
    Xt = trans(X)
    xto, yto = offset(Xt[:,0],Xt[:,1],o*dpi/72. )
    Xto = np.c_[xto, yto]
    Xo = inv(Xto)
    return Xo[:,0], Xo[:,1]


# some single points
y = np.array([1,2,2,3,3,0])    
x = np.arange(len(y))
#or try a sinus
x = np.linspace(0,9)
y=np.sin(x)*x/3.


fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2.5), dpi=dpi)

cols = ["#fff40b", "#00e103", "#ff9921", "#3a00ef", "#ff2121", "#af00e7"]
lw = 2.
lines = []
for i in range(len(cols)):
    l, = plt.plot(x,y, lw=lw, color=cols[i])
    lines.append(l)


def plot_rainbow(event=None):
    xr = range(6); yr = range(6); 
    xr[0],yr[0] = offset_curve(ax, x,y, lw/2.)
    xr[1],yr[1] = offset_curve(ax, x,y, -lw/2.)
    xr[2],yr[2] = offset_curve(ax, xr[0],yr[0], lw)
    xr[3],yr[3] = offset_curve(ax, xr[1],yr[1], -lw)
    xr[4],yr[4] = offset_curve(ax, xr[2],yr[2], lw)
    xr[5],yr[5] = offset_curve(ax, xr[3],yr[3], -lw)

    for i  in range(6):     
        lines[i].set_data(xr[i], yr[i])


plot_rainbow()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", plot_rainbow)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", plot_rainbow)

plt.savefig(__file__+".png", dpi=dpi)
plt.show()
```

I try to compile the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165631/in-matplotlib-how-can-i-plot-a-multi-colored-line-like-a-rainbow) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range` object can not be set.

You can change it to list by:

```
 xr = list(range(6)); yr = list(range(6));
```

But I don't understand why you use in `range` in the first place. If you just wan to initialize a list, I would go with something like:

```
xr,  yr = 6*[None], 6*[None]
```

Ofcourse you can put `0` or whatever instead `None`

Answer (score 1):

`range()` returns `range` object instead of list. To convert:

```
xr = list(range(6))
```