# How to plot the figure in the desired fashion?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

How to edit this code to have the same width and colour map as in the following figure? The script is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165631/in-matplotlib-how-can-i-plot-a-multi-colored-line-like-a-rainbow) question.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dpi = 100

def offset(x,y, o):
    """ Offset coordinates given by array x,y by o """
    X = np.c_[x,y].T
    m = np.array([[0,-1],[1,0]])
    R = np.zeros_like(X)
    S = X[:,2:]-X[:,:-2]
    R[:,1:-1] = np.dot(m, S)
    R[:,0] = np.dot(m, X[:,1]-X[:,0])
    R[:,-1] = np.dot(m, X[:,-1]-X[:,-2])
    On = R/np.sqrt(R[0,:]**2+R[1,:]**2)*o
    Out = On+X
    return Out[0,:], Out[1,:]


def offset_curve(ax, x,y, o):
    """ Offset array x,y in data coordinates
        by o in points """
    trans = ax.transData.transform
    inv = ax.transData.inverted().transform
    X = np.c_[x,y]
    Xt = trans(X)
    xto, yto = offset(Xt[:,0],Xt[:,1],o*dpi/72. )
    Xto = np.c_[xto, yto]
    Xo = inv(Xto)
    return Xo[:,0], Xo[:,1]

x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y = -(1/4*x**4 - 1.6*x**2) 


fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2.5), dpi=dpi)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greys_r')
lw = 2.
lines = []
width_l = ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0]
for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 40):
    l, = ax.plot(x, y - t * 0.1 * width_l, color=cmap(t/2 + 0.25))
    lines.append(l)

def plot_rainbow(event=None):
    # initialization of lists
    xr,  yr = 6*[None], 6*[None]
    xr[0],yr[0] = offset_curve(ax, x,y, lw/2.)
    xr[1],yr[1] = offset_curve(ax, x,y, -lw/2.)
    xr[2],yr[2] = offset_curve(ax, xr[0],yr[0], lw)
    xr[3],yr[3] = offset_curve(ax, xr[1],yr[1], -lw)
    xr[4],yr[4] = offset_curve(ax, xr[2],yr[2], lw)
    xr[5],yr[5] = offset_curve(ax, xr[3],yr[3], -lw)

    for i  in range(6):     
        lines[i].set_data(xr[i], yr[i])

plot_rainbow()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("resize_event", plot_rainbow)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", plot_rainbow)

plt.show()
```

The figure above was created by the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math 

dpi = 100

# Function for plotting parallels to curves
def get_parallels(length=.1):
    
    px, py = [], []
    
    for idx in range(len(x)-1):
        x0, y0, xa, ya = x[idx], y[idx], x[idx+1], y[idx+1]
        dx, dy = xa-x0, ya-y0
        norm = math.hypot(dx, dy) * 1/length
        dx /= norm
        dy /= norm        
        px.append(x0-dy)
        py.append(y0+dx)
    return px, py

fig, ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(4,2.5), dpi=dpi)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('Greys_r')

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 100)
y = -x**2
ax.set_ylim(-1.02, 0.3)
ax.scatter(1/2*(ax.get_xlim()[0] + ax.get_xlim()[1]), 0.145, marker = 'o', s=900, facecolors='none')
width_l = ax.get_ylim()[1] - ax.get_ylim()[0]
for t in np.linspace(0, 1, 40): 
    length =  -0.1*width_l*t
    ax.plot(*get_parallels(length=length), color=cmap(t/2 + 0.25))

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Several curves are plotted in camp and the length is set.

I would like to have the same "shadow" for the curve in the first scrip. How to do that, please?